# Mobile Browser - Back Button

Tags: iphone, android

I have a doubt. Please make me clear. 
I know we could not disable the mobile browser back button. But,

Is it possible to change the events of **mobile browsers** back button ?
[Mobile Browser :iPhone - Safari, Android - Chrome , W7 - IE , Opera Mobile,

Regards,
Girija

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot change the functions of the mobile browsers because the mobile browser is it's own application. It would be like saying can anyone just change what the back button on your application does?